# vuex namespaced mapState with multiple modules

Tags: javascript, module, namespaces, vuex

I must be missing something. How can I use vuex mapState with multiple modules?

As far as understand, besides passing an object as argument, namespaced mapState can take two arguments: namespace and an array of object names denoting the members of modules. Like this

```
// an imcomplete vue
export default {
   computed: mapState('user', ['addresses', 'creditCards']) 
};
```

But what if i'd like to add objects from a second namespace to computed? e.g. vendor like this:

```
mapState('vendor', ['products', 'ratings'])
```

Currently I am merging both mapState like this:

```
let userMapState = mapState('user', ['addresses', 'creditCards']); 
let vendorMapState = mapState ('vendor', ['products', 'ratings']);
let mergedMapStates = Object.assign({}, userMapState, vendorMapState);
```

And then:

```
// an imcomplete vue
export default {
    computed: mergedMapStates
};
```

It works, but it's hardly the right way to do it. Or is it?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
computed: {
  ...mapState('user', ['addresses', 'creditCards']),
  ...mapState('vendor', ['products', 'ratings']) 
}
```

Comment: I misread those three dots as ellipsis in the documenation. I'm still haven't gotten used to the spread operator.

Comment: Yes, but how do you then reference addresses from within the component?

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts like any other data e.g. `{{ addresses }}` or `<div v-for="address in addresses">`

Comment: I forgot the comma between the two calls 

Answer (score 23):

This is from the vuex docs, you can do it all within one `...mapState({})`. [Documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace)

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    a: state => state.some.nested.module.a,
    b: state => state.some.nested.module.b
  })
},
```

**Edit 2019**

You can also pass a path to your nested module and make the module references cleaner (thanks [@gijswijs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119129/gijswijs))

```
computed: {
  ...mapState('some/nested/module', {
    a: state => state.a,
    b: state => state.b
  })
},
```

Comment: The documentation (now) specifically states that this way of doing things "can get a bit verbose", so the alternative, explained below, is to "pass the module namespace string as the first argument to the helpers so that all bindings are done using that module as the context"

Answer (score 3):

You can try this if you have no too many namespaces:

```
    ...mapState({
      userAddresses: 'user/addresses',
      userCreditCards: 'user/creditCards'

      vendorProducts: 'vendor/products',
      vendorRatings: 'vendor/ratings',          
    })
```

Comment: This does not work with Nuxt 2.15 or lower at least

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Object.assign like this. Similar to your current solution but a bit cleaner.

```
    computed: Object.assign(
        mapState('user', ['addresses', 'creditCards']),
        mapState('vendor', ['products', 'ratings']
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of spread operator to access multiple module State values

```js
 ...mapState('user', {
     isLoggedIn: ({ activeUser }) => !!activeUser?.id
  }),
   ...mapState('quizzes', ['getCategories'])
```