# Vuex modules namespacing references - how to mapState correctly

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have two modules as follows:

```
const surfers = {
  namespaced: true,
}
```

```
const surfGroups = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
     fetchingSurfersLoading: true,
  }
}
```

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    surfers: surfers,
    surfGroups: surfGroups
  }
});
```

The two namespaced modules have state etc. which I have just left out for brevity.

I am mapping the state from the namespaced stores to a component as follows:

```
...mapState({
   fetchingSurfersLoading: state => state.surfers.fetchingSurfersLoading,
   fetchingSurfersSuccess: state => state.surfers.fetchingSurfersSuccess,
   fetchingSurfSessionsLoading: state => state.surfGroups.fetchingSurfSessionsLoading,
   fetchingSurfSessionsSuccess: state => state.surfGroups.fetchingSurfSessionsSuccess,
   creatingSurfGroupLoading: state => state.surfGroups.creatingSurfGroupLoading,
   creatingSurfGroupSuccess: state => state.surfGroups.creatingSurfGroupSuccess,
}),
```

However, the state is not, unfortunately mapped, as I have a component which does not trigger:

```
<Loader v-if="creatingSurfGroupLoading || fetchingSurfSessionsLoading" />
```

Also, watching the various parameters does not trigger any underlying changes:

```
  watch: {
    fetchingSurfSessionsLoading() {
      console.log(this.fetchingSurfSessionsLoading);
    },
  },
```

Alas, nothing is logged in the console, ever...

If I used multiple spread operators for mappped State:

```
    ...mapState('surfGroups/', [
      'fetchingSurfSessionsLoading',
      'fetchingSurfSessionsSuccess',
      'creatingSurfGroupLoading',
      'creatingSurfGroupSuccess',
    ]),
    ...mapState('surfers/', [
      'fetchingSurfersLoading',
      'fetchingSurfersSuccess',
    ]),
```

Accessing fetchingSurfersSuccess say, in the template:

```
<Loader v-if="creatingSurfGroupLoading || fetchingSurfSessionsLoading" />
```

Does not work, whatsoever. The same with the watching and logging tests, nothing changes/updates. Before I namespaced the store with sepearte modules, this was all fine.

What is weird, is my actions are mapped for each of the different namespaces...and they are working?

Comment: Don't this work ? `...mapState("surfGroups", ["fetchingSurfersLoading"])`

Comment: @Seblor It doesn't as far as I know because I need to map state from two namespaces. So some sort of combination of `...mapState("surfers", ["fetchingSurfersLoading"])` and `...mapState("surfGroups", ["fetchingSurfSessionsLoading"])`

Comment: Why not use getters, then ? The getters can access the root state (third argument). Also, unless you need this aggregated value somewhere else in your app, you could use the 2 mapState and create computed property to aggregate them.

Comment: There's nothing in the documentation on how to use namespaced getters...

Comment: Just tried using getters and still nothing is being logged in the watcher...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vuex namespaced mapState with multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594244/vuex-namespaced-mapstate-with-multiple-modules)

Comment: @Plpicard I looked at that, so using multiple spread operators....but alas, it didn't work. How do you reference each of the mapped states in that example answer?

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos can you update your question to add the getters version ?

Comment: @Seblor Getters aren't really working for me.

Comment: Someone needs to explain how we then reference the state using multiple spread operators with the module namespace prefix? There's nothing in that question or is the documentation!

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos The mapState needs to be in the computed block to be reactive ` computed: {...mapState("surfers",["fetchingSurfersLoading","fetchingSurfersSuccess"]), ...mapState("surfGroups", ["fetchingSurfSessionsLoading", "fetchingSurfSessionsSuccess", "creatingSurfGroupLoading", "creatingSurfGroupSuccess"])`  The mapping is `...mapState(ModuleName, list of the property in the state by exact name)`  Doc https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html

Comment: @Plpicard Yes, I have added the two mapped state spreads to the computed directive block but nothing is being computed, watchers aren't updating or variables being rendered in the template...

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos More of the source code or a repository and some information on the version of the used modules (Vuex, Vue) would be helpful.

Comment: @Plpicard Latest versions of Vue and Vuex. I will add full code, but it is cumbersome.

Comment: @Plpicard I think it is something to do with my mutation commits inside the store: `[vuex] unknown local mutation type: surfers/SET_FETCHING_SURFERS_LOADING, global type: surfers/surfers/SET_FETCHING_SURFERS_LOADING`

Comment: @Plpicard Scrap that, removing the namespacing from the mutations has worked. And also I was mutation this.something and now state.something (!!)