# Rename Vue mapState state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In my computed, I have two "loading" states that I want to track. Is there a way to add an alias to the other state with this syntax?

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState('barcodes', ['barcodes', 'loading', 'pagination']),
    ...mapState('users', ['user', 'loading']), // add an alias for this "loading"
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

**mapState has supported an object way, something like:** (Specific alias for only 1 field)

```
computed: {
  ...mapState('barcodes', {
    barcodesLoading: state => state.loading,
  })
}
```

**Or by namespace:** (If you want to wrap all user state into the userData namespace)

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
      barcodeData: 'barcodes',
      userData: 'users'
  })
}
```

on Template:

```
<div>{{barcodeData.loading}}</div>
```

There is another thread for your reference:

[vuex namespaced mapState with multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594244/vuex-namespaced-mapstate-with-multiple-modules)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not absolutely sure, because I can't check it out right now. But AFAIK you should just try this:

```js
computed: {
    ...mapState('barcodes', {barcodes:'barcodes', alias1:'loading', pagination:'pagination'}),
    ...mapState('users', {user:'user', alias2:'loading'}), // add an alias for this "loading"
  }
```

I.e. use object instead of array.